# Defined max. and min. size is somewhere overridden

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am currently developing a `gui` which content is defined in a specific `xml` file. I have so called `Widgets`. These widgets have it's own implemented logic plus have a defined width and height. Both, the `minimum` and `maximum size`, are fix and cannot be changed. A Widget is a `UserControl`.

Screenshot showing the fix max. and min. size:

[image]

For an right now unknown reason the size is during runtime different. As seen on the following screenshot:
[image]

Beside the designer file of the `SingleplayerWidget` my own source code, of the SingeplayerWidget, is following:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Racetrack.Controller;

namespace Racetrack.View.Widgets
{
public partial class SingleplayerWidget : UserControl
{
    private GameController Controller;

    public SingleplayerWidget()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.extendedTextBoxPlayername.SetPlaceholder("Choose a playername");
    }

    public SingleplayerWidget(GameController controller)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Controller = controller;
        this.extendedTextBoxPlayername.SetPlaceholder("Choose a playername");

        this.colorDialogCarColor = new ColorDialog();
        this.colorDialogCarColor.Color = Color.Black;
        this.panelCarColor.BackColor = this.colorDialogCarColor.Color;
    }

    private void menuButtonChangeCarColor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.colorDialogCarColor.ShowDialog();
        this.panelCarColor.BackColor = this.colorDialogCarColor.Color;
    }
}
}
```

And this is the designer source code:

```
namespace Racetrack.View.Widgets
{
partial class SingleplayerWidget
{
    /// <summary> 
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary> 
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Component Designer generated code

    /// <summary> 
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.labelWidgetHeadline = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.labelPlayername = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.colorDialogCarColor = new System.Windows.Forms.ColorDialog();
        this.labelCarColor = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.panelCarColor = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
        this.menuButtonChangeCarColor = new Racetrack.View.Forms.MenuButton();
        this.extendedTextBoxPlayername = new Racetrack.View.Forms.ExtendedTextBox();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // labelWidgetHeadline
        // 
        this.labelWidgetHeadline.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
        this.labelWidgetHeadline.AutoSize = true;
        this.labelWidgetHeadline.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 13.8F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.labelWidgetHeadline.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(14, 8);
        this.labelWidgetHeadline.Name = "labelWidgetHeadline";
        this.labelWidgetHeadline.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(188, 29);
        this.labelWidgetHeadline.TabIndex = 2;
        this.labelWidgetHeadline.Text = "Your Character";
        // 
        // labelPlayername
        // 
        this.labelPlayername.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
        this.labelPlayername.AutoSize = true;
        this.labelPlayername.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(17, 58);
        this.labelPlayername.Name = "labelPlayername";
        this.labelPlayername.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(87, 17);
        this.labelPlayername.TabIndex = 3;
        this.labelPlayername.Text = "Playername:";
        // 
        // labelCarColor
        // 
        this.labelCarColor.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
        this.labelCarColor.AutoSize = true;
        this.labelCarColor.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(17, 120);
        this.labelCarColor.Name = "labelCarColor";
        this.labelCarColor.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(69, 17);
        this.labelCarColor.TabIndex = 5;
        this.labelCarColor.Text = "Car color:";
        // 
        // panelCarColor
        // 
        this.panelCarColor.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
        this.panelCarColor.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20, 140);
        this.panelCarColor.Name = "panelCarColor";
        this.panelCarColor.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 37);
        this.panelCarColor.TabIndex = 8;
        // 
        // menuButtonChangeCarColor
        // 
        this.menuButtonChangeCarColor.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
        this.menuButtonChangeCarColor.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.GradientInactiveCaption;
        this.menuButtonChangeCarColor.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
        this.menuButtonChangeCarColor.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
        this.menuButtonChangeCarColor.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(119, 140);
        this.menuButtonChangeCarColor.Name = "menuButtonChangeCarColor";
        this.menuButtonChangeCarColor.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 37);
        this.menuButtonChangeCarColor.TabIndex = 9;
        this.menuButtonChangeCarColor.Text = "change";
        this.menuButtonChangeCarColor.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        this.menuButtonChangeCarColor.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.menuButtonChangeCarColor_Click);
        // 
        // extendedTextBoxPlayername
        // 
        this.extendedTextBoxPlayername.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
        this.extendedTextBoxPlayername.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(19, 83);
        this.extendedTextBoxPlayername.Name = "extendedTextBoxPlayername";
        this.extendedTextBoxPlayername.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(180, 22);
        this.extendedTextBoxPlayername.TabIndex = 4;
        // 
        // SingleplayerWidget
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window;
        this.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        this.Controls.Add(this.menuButtonChangeCarColor);
        this.Controls.Add(this.panelCarColor);
        this.Controls.Add(this.labelCarColor);
        this.Controls.Add(this.extendedTextBoxPlayername);
        this.Controls.Add(this.labelPlayername);
        this.Controls.Add(this.labelWidgetHeadline);
        this.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(225, 325);
        this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(225, 325);
        this.Name = "SingleplayerWidget";
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(225, 325);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.Label labelWidgetHeadline;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label labelPlayername;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ColorDialog colorDialogCarColor;
    private Forms.ExtendedTextBox extendedTextBoxPlayername;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label labelCarColor;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panelCarColor;
    private Forms.MenuButton menuButtonChangeCarColor;
}
}
```

My `GameConfigurationView` has `AutoSize = False`. My `Widgets` have the same property value and the source code (I exclude the designer file as of the question length). *I know the source code needs to be cleaned up later.*

As you can see the following source code I assign the size as well, when initializing a new widget. This does not work either.

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using Racetrack.Controller;
using Racetrack.View.Widgets;

namespace Racetrack.View
{
public partial class GameConfigurationView : Form
{
    protected GameController Controller { get; set; }
    protected MapSelectionWidget MapSelectionWidget { get; set; }
    protected SingleplayerWidget SingleplayerWidget { get; set; }

    protected Point GuiBuilderNextLocation { get; set; }
    protected Size GuiBuilderFinalSize { get; set; }
    protected int GuiBuilderTallestElementInCurrentRow { get; set; }
    protected int GuiBuilderWidthOfCurrentRow { get; set; }

    public GameConfigurationView(GameController controller)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Controller = controller;
        this.GuiBuilder();
        this.menuButtonStartGame.Width = this.Width;
        this.Size = this.GuiBuilderFinalSize;
    }

    private void GameConfigurationView_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Controller.ShowStartView();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Builds the gui based on the configuration of the selected GameVariant.
    /// </summary>
    protected void GuiBuilder()
    {
        XmlNodeList configuration = this.Controller.SelectedGameVariant.GameConfigurationView;
        this.GuiBuilderNextLocation = new Point(0, 0);
        this.GuiBuilderFinalSize = new Size(0, 0);
        this.GuiBuilderTallestElementInCurrentRow = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < configuration.Count; i++)
        {
            this.BuildOneRowFromGameVariantConfiguration(configuration[i].SelectNodes("elements/element"));
        }
    }

    protected void BuildOneRowFromGameVariantConfiguration(XmlNodeList widgets)
    {
        this.GuiBuilderNextLocation = new Point(
            this.GuiBuilderNextLocation.X - 1,
            this.GuiBuilderNextLocation.Y - 1
        );
        for (int i = 0; i < widgets.Count; i++)
        {
            this.GuiBuilderNextLocation = new Point(
                this.GuiBuilderNextLocation.X - 1,
                this.GuiBuilderNextLocation.Y
            );
            string elementType = widgets[i].SelectSingleNode("type").InnerText;
            string elementWidth = widgets[i].SelectSingleNode("width").InnerText;
            switch (elementType)
            {
                case "SingleplayerWidget":
                    this.AddSingleplayerWidgetToGui();
                    break;
                case "MapSelectionWidget":
                    this.AddMapSelectionWidgetToGui();
                    break;
                case "MultiplayerWidget":

                    break;
                case "NetworkClientWidget":

                    break;
                case "NetworkHostWidget":

                    break;
                case "startbutton":

                    break;
            }
        }

        // After the row reset & update
        this.GuiBuilderNextLocation = new Point(
            0,
            this.GuiBuilderTallestElementInCurrentRow + this.GuiBuilderNextLocation.Y
        );
        if (this.GuiBuilderWidthOfCurrentRow > this.GuiBuilderFinalSize.Width)
        {
            this.GuiBuilderFinalSize = new Size(
                this.GuiBuilderWidthOfCurrentRow,
                this.GuiBuilderFinalSize.Height + this.GuiBuilderTallestElementInCurrentRow
            );
        }
        else
        {
            this.GuiBuilderFinalSize = new Size(
                this.GuiBuilderFinalSize.Width,
                this.GuiBuilderFinalSize.Height + this.GuiBuilderTallestElementInCurrentRow
            );
        }
        this.GuiBuilderTallestElementInCurrentRow = 0;
        this.GuiBuilderWidthOfCurrentRow = 0;
    }

    protected void AddSingleplayerWidgetToGui()
    {
        // Add to gui
        this.SingleplayerWidget = new SingleplayerWidget(this.Controller);
        this.SingleplayerWidget.BackColor = SystemColors.ButtonHighlight;
        this.SingleplayerWidget.Location = this.GuiBuilderNextLocation;
        this.SingleplayerWidget.Name = "SingleplayerWidget";
        this.SingleplayerWidget.Size = new Size(225, 325);
        this.SingleplayerWidget.TabIndex = 1;
        this.SingleplayerWidget.Show();
        this.Controls.Add(this.SingleplayerWidget);

        // Update next location
        this.GuiBuilderNextLocation = new Point(
            this.SingleplayerWidget.Width + this.GuiBuilderNextLocation.X,
            this.GuiBuilderNextLocation.Y
        );

        if (this.SingleplayerWidget.Height > this.GuiBuilderTallestElementInCurrentRow)
        {
            this.GuiBuilderTallestElementInCurrentRow = this.SingleplayerWidget.Height;
        }
        this.GuiBuilderWidthOfCurrentRow += this.SingleplayerWidget.Width + 1;
    }

    protected void AddMapSelectionWidgetToGui()
    {
        // Add to gui
        this.MapSelectionWidget = new MapSelectionWidget(this.Controller);
        this.MapSelectionWidget.BackColor = SystemColors.ButtonHighlight;
        this.MapSelectionWidget.Location = this.GuiBuilderNextLocation;
        this.MapSelectionWidget.Name = "MapSelectionWidget";
        this.MapSelectionWidget.Size = new Size(510, 325);
        this.MapSelectionWidget.TabIndex = 0;
        this.MapSelectionWidget.Show();
        this.Controls.Add(this.MapSelectionWidget);

        // Update next location
        this.GuiBuilderNextLocation = new Point(
            this.MapSelectionWidget.Width + this.GuiBuilderNextLocation.X,
            this.GuiBuilderNextLocation.Y
        );

        if (this.MapSelectionWidget.Height > this.GuiBuilderTallestElementInCurrentRow)
        {
            this.GuiBuilderTallestElementInCurrentRow = this.MapSelectionWidget.Height;
        }
        this.GuiBuilderWidthOfCurrentRow += this.MapSelectionWidget.Width + 1;
    }
}
}
```

I appreciate your help :)

Comment: Does the parent control you're adding this widget into have `AutoSize = true` so it can expand to hold it?  Many container controls will smash their children to fit regardless of the their min/max size values.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The `Widgets` and the `GameConfigurationView` have `AutoSize = False`. I have updated my question. Among others it includes the source code of the GameConfigurationView class.

Comment: What is the `AutoScaleMode` of user control, container, form?

Comment: @Ulugbek Umirov Oh, my bad! Here we go: `Widget` =  `AutoScaleMode = Font`. `GameConfView` = `AutoScaleMode = Font`

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get things working.

What did I do? Due to OOP I have implemented a `BaseWidget` containing `Label(s)`, `Configuration` etc. which are available/required on every `Widget`. This `BaseWidget` has following settings:

- `AutoScaleMode = Font`
- `AutoSize = True`
- `AutoSizeMode = GrowOnly`
- `Size = 275; 193` Though the size will be overridden in the respective `SubWidget`

In each `SubWidget` I add `Forms` with `Anchor = AnchorStyles.None`

The `GameConfigurationView` is defined as follows:

- `AutoScaleMode = None`
- `AutoSize = True`
- `AutoSizeMode = GrowOnly`

To be honest I am not sure which of these settings are really necessary by now but I have these settings and it works. As I have more information I edit this answer.